# drawing rectangle on existing uiview issue

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4.2

I have a view controller based app that contains several views that I display/hide depending on some logic. I would like to draw a rectangle which will be the size of the UIView in order to give it like a frame/border shape.

I'm having issue drawing a rectangle. I understand that the following code should do it but I'm not sure why this method is not being called or triggered. I also didn't see the (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method generated anywhere so I placed it myself. Not sure what I'm missing here..

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
{   
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // yellow line

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50.0, 50.0); //start point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250.0, 100.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250.0, 350.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50.0, 350.0); // end path

    CGContextClosePath(context); // close path

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 8.0); // this is set from now on until you explicitly change it

    CGContextStrokePath(context); // do actual stroking

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5); // green color, half transparent
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(20.0, 250.0, 128.0, 128.0)); // a square at the bottom left-hand corner
}
```

Comment: `drawRect:` is a method on UIView, so did you put this code in the view controller or did you subclass UIView?

Comment: @Brian, i placed it inside the view controller. what subclass the UIView means and for what purpose? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need to do is add a simple rectangular border, just do the following in your `viewWillAppear:` for your view controller.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   //Simple border on the main view
   self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
   self.view.layer.borderWidth = 2;

   //Or a simple rectangle to place at x,h within the main view 
   UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
   test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self.view addSubview:test];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. I added      self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;  to create round corners and it does that well however it behind the round corner shows up white background while my uiview background is black. Any idea why this white background is showing while the corners are shown ?

Comment: Are you sure you want a rounded border on your main view? If so, maybe it would be better to set the background color of self.view to whatever color you want the corners to be, and then add another UIView (like in the above example code) with rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but do you tell the `UIView` to redisplay itself?

```
[myUIView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Only then does the `drawRect:` get called.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a class(`YourView`) which is subclass of `UIView`. You implement code in your viewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   YourView *temp = [[YourView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

    [self.view addSubview:temp];
}
```

You write your method(`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`) in `YourView.m` file.
Try like this. I think it will helpful to you.